# UIbutton imageview is not same in every cell of tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

could anyone help me Im pretty desperate with my tableview.
Basically I have this tableview with button as checkbox

this is how I suppy my data to button

```
BOOL isChecked = [model.isChecked boolValue];
    self.checkBoxButton.selected = isChecked;
    self.checkBoxButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
    self.checkBoxButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
    self.checkBoxButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

this is my tableview looks like

[image]

I would like my uibutton image be same size as the big ones.

when my view loads the sizes of images is fine..however when i begin the touch of button the images begin to collapse, it even put the big ones smaller and smaller ones bigger randomly.

Answer (score 0):

**Per update**

Looks to me like the button isn't set to `UIButtonTypeCustom` and the system is somehow adjusting it on the touch began event. Try changing the button type to custom.

---

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method, *after* you dequeue a reusable cell, try resetting the checkbox to either nil or its default image, or try forcing its BOOL value to false. Once you've reset the image, then try calling the method (not setting the property) for selected:

```
BOOL isChecked = [model.isChecked boolValue];
[self.checkBoxButton setSelected:isChecked];
```

My vague guess to what's going on here is that somehow the value from the model is being retrieved before the cell is dequeued, and thus it retains some value from the last time the cell was used. If you clear it out after dequeuing, then set the value from the model, it should set it correctly.

Comment: the displaying of image is fine..however if i begin to touch the checkbox the size collapse

Comment: OK, well you didn't make that clear at all in your question.

Comment: @MohsenHosseinpour i just taped the button(check image) then modified the model then [tableview reloaddata]

Comment: Does this happen immediately on touch, or after you call `reloadData`?

Comment: @brandonscript it happen when reloadData

Comment: Then it's a data problem and has nothing to do with the touch actions. Try my original answer.

Comment: you should use UIImage 
*btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[btnTwo setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
for setting the image of button